# Dynamically inserting dom nodes with event bound functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

First stackoverflow question so be gentle :)

Im making a chrome webapp consisting entirely of javascript and I want to code as much as posible myself. Therefor I have to make some functions like a system prompt/warning on unsaved document.

To make this prompt function as portable as possible the logic goes as such:

```
function prompt (String message, assocArray commandname:function)  
Print message  
for each command  
make button and .bind click(function) to it
```

Obviously im using jQuery for this.

The question is how can I bind a function on click event to a not inserted Dom element without hardcoding the selectors, and in as few lines of code as possible?

The next code is erroneous but it represents what I want to do.

```
var message = "Document is not saved, do you want to save it now?";

    var options = {
        "yes": function(){alert("yes")},
        "no": function(){alert("no")},
        "cancel": function(){alert("cancel")}
    }

    systemPrompt = function(message, options){
        $("body").append("<div class='prompt'><div class='prompt_message'><p>"+message+"</p><div class='options'></div></div></div");
        var optionsContainer = $('.promt_mesage .options').append("<table><tr></tr></table>");
        for(command in options){
            optionContainer.append("<td>"+command+"</td>").bind('click', function(){
                options[command];
            });
        }
    };
```

Question related to this: How can I grabb a newly inserted dom element? Without having to hardcode the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has this problem solved thanks to Event Delegation. Try the  [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method.

You can use `$('div.prompt').delegate('td', 'click', function(){ ... })` even before the DOM of your table has been constructed. It will automagically work for elements added later in time.